# Socket taking too long to close

Tags: php, sockets, minecraft

I have sockets querying a game server on a few pages in my application. I have an issue that when i navigate too quickly between the pages, the socket has no closed properly and the error i get is this;

```
socket_recv() [function.socket-recv]: unable to read from socket [104]: Connection reset by peer
```

I have to wait around 4-5 seconds after each page has fully loaded, for it to close.

Here is the code for the socket;

```
function QueryMinecraft( $IP, $Port, $Timeout =1 )
{
    $Socket = Socket_Create( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP );

    Socket_Set_Option( $Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array( 'sec' => (int)$Timeout, 'usec' => 0 ) );

    if( $Socket === FALSE || @Socket_Connect( $Socket, $IP, (int)$Port ) === FALSE )
    {
        Socket_Close( $Socket );
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        Socket_Close( $Socket );
        return TRUE;
    }      
    Socket_Close( $Socket );                  
}
```

And here is the code for the socket on the other page;

```
function QueryMinecraft( $IP, $Port, $Timeout = 3 )
{
    $Socket = Socket_Create( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP );

    Socket_Set_Option( $Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array( 'sec' => (int)$Timeout, 'usec' => 0 ) );

    if( $Socket === FALSE || @Socket_Connect( $Socket, $IP, (int)$Port ) === FALSE )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    Socket_Send( $Socket, "\xFE", 1, 0 );
    $Len = Socket_Recv( $Socket, $Data,256, 0 );


    if( $Len < 4 || $Data[ 0 ] != "\xFF" )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $Data = SubStr( $Data, 3 );
    $Data = iconv( 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8', $Data );
    $Data = Explode( "\xA7", $Data );

    return Array(
        'HostName'   => SubStr( $Data[ 0 ], 0, -1 ),
        'Players'    => isset( $Data[ 1 ] ) ? IntVal( $Data[ 1 ] ) : 0,
        'MaxPlayers' => isset( $Data[ 2 ] ) ? IntVal( $Data[ 2 ] ) : 0
    );
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Woohoo, specific knowledge I know a lot about! There should be a minecraft tag.

I believe this is actually a minecraft server limitation, as opposed to a problem with your php code.  You may notice that if you are using the minecraft client and you visit the multiplayer page several times quickly, you will experience the same issue (connections to servers to query player count and MOTD will be denied).  It resolves itself if you wait 5 or 6 seconds between visits.

Your solution might therefore be to cache the response from servers for 10 seconds or 30 seconds or so, so that the server doesn't deny them.

I don't know if you have a local SQL database you can use, but you should be able to set yourself up a table containing the server ip (not the hostname, which is not guaranteed to be unique.  The IP isn't either but its a better bet), the MOTD, the current and max players, and a last-checked timestamp.  You can simply do your database query, check the timestamp to make sure the cached value hasnt expired, and if it has, query the server directly and store the result in the database.

Comment: It's been a reaaaaally long time since I've poked around in the server code, but judging by the universality of this behavior, its a behavior of the server.

Comment: Okay, its really annoying, might have to make pages load slower lol :L

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i might pause page load by 3 seconds of something.

Comment: Look into the caching suggestion.  It has merit.  Also, a simple page load delay only fixes the problem if only one person is ever viewing the page, it will still break if more than one try (unless you stagger their requests so a maximum of one pageload every 3 seconds happens, which is a horrible idea).  If you absolutely HAD to keep track of players in real time, you could write a plugin for the server that will open a socket to your database backend and provide real time updates for the MOTD and players, but that would be a lot of work.

Comment: Hi, i will try that, how can i go about caching it?

Comment: You want to use a database.  Google around for "set up sql server on [my platform]"

Comment: Some basic SQL tutorials might be in order too, google for that too.  I'll design your database for you; you need 1 table (call it ServerResponseCache) and 6 fields (call them ServerIp, ServerPort, Motd, PlayersNow, PlayersMax, and Timestamp).  ServerIP needs to be a string of max length 40 (to accomodate IPv6), Motd needs to be a longish string (512 maybe), Timestamp will need to be a datetime, and all other fields can be integers. When you make a request, if the current time is later than Timestamp, recheck the server. When you insert into the database, set Timestamp to NOW + some timeout.